# Make data stored in provider persistent

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I'm using a modal in Ionic 2 to do some stuff that resembles a music player. Within this modal, I am setting several variables that I want to persist even if the modal closes and a new modal is created. To persist the data I am storing it in a service just like in Angular 1.

My page component:

```
this.playerService.setRelease(this.params.get('release'));
console.log(this.playerService.getStoredRelease()); // This works right after it is being stored.
```

My service:

```
setRelease(release) {
  this.release = release;
}

getStoredRelease() {
  return this.release;
}
```

This is all being done in a modal. Once I call `this.viewCtrl.dismiss();` and reopen the modal using Ionic's

```
openModal(release) {
  let modal = Modal.create(ModalsContentPage, release);
  this.navController.present(modal);
}
```

I call console.log(this.playerService.getStoredRelease()); before setting it and it is undefined. How can I get it to where the service will persist data. Should I use something else?

player.ts

```
import {Component, Renderer} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, Platform, NavParams, ViewController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {PlayerService} from '../../providers/player-service/player-service';
import {ConnectService} from '../../providers/connect-service/connect-service';
declare var $: JQueryStatic;

@Component({
  templateUrl: './build/pages/player/player.html',
  providers: [PlayerService, ConnectService]
})

export class ModalsContentPage {
  release;
  art;
  public song: any;
  artists;
  title;
  private time: any;
  private pos: any;
  public counter: any;

  constructor(
    public platform: Platform,
    public params: NavParams,
    public viewCtrl: ViewController,
    public playerService: PlayerService,
    public connectService: ConnectService
  ) {
    this.time = {};
    this.time.percent = 0;
    this.playerService.getStoredRelease();
    console.log(this.params.get('release'));
      if (this.playerService.getStoredRelease() === this.params.get('release')) {
        console.log('wew lad i did it');
      } else {
      this.playerService.setRelease(this.params.get('release'));
      console.log(this.playerService.getStoredRelease());
      this.release = this.params.get('release');
      this.fetchSong(this.release._id);
      this.art = this.release.artwork_url;
    }
  }

  fetchSong(id) {
    this.connectService.loadSongs(id)
      .then(data => {
        this.song = data[0];
        //this.songs = data ##The song var will just be at the index specified. 
        this.artists = this.song.artistsTitle;
        this.title = this.song.title;
        this.init();
      })
  }

  init() {
    $('.range-slider').on("touchstart", () => this.touchActivate());
    $('.range-slider').on("touchend", () => this.seekPos());
    this.playerService.initUrl("http://www.xamuel.com/blank-mp3-files/5min.mp3");
    this.subCounter();
  }

  subCounter() {
    this.counter = this.playerService.counter(this.song).subscribe(data => {
      this.pos = data;
      this.time.position = Math.round(this.pos);
      this.time.dur = this.song.duration - this.time.position;
      this.time.durMinutes = Math.floor(this.time.dur / 60);
      this.time.durSeconds = ('0' + Math.ceil(this.time.dur - this.time.durMinutes * 60)).slice(-2);
      this.time.posMinutes = Math.floor(this.time.position / 60);
      this.time.posSeconds = ('0' + Math.ceil(this.time.position - this.time.posMinutes * 60)).slice(-2);
      this.time.percent = this.time.position / this.song.duration * 100;
    })
  }

  dismiss() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
  }

  touchActivate() {
    this.counter.unsubscribe();
  }

  seekPos() {
    var ms = (this.song.duration * 1000) * (this.time.percent / 100);
    this.playerService.seek(ms);
    this.subCounter();
  }
}
```

player-service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {MediaPlugin} from 'ionic-native';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class PlayerService {
  private media: any;
  public release: any;
  public song: any;
  private time: any;
  public playing: boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.time = {};
  }

  initUrl(release) {
    this.media = new MediaPlugin(release);
    this.media.play();
    console.log("ASDF");
    this.media.setVolume('0.0');
    //this.counter(null);
  }

  setRelease(release) {
    this.release = release;
    console.log('got it');
  }

  getStoredRelease() {
    //console.log(this.release);
    return this.release;
  }

  counter(song) {
    return Observable
      .interval(500)
      .flatMap(() => {
        return this.media.getCurrentPosition();
      });
  }

  seek(pos) {
    this.media.seekTo(pos);
  }

  pause() {
    this.playing = false;
    this.media.pause();
  }

  play() {
    this.playing = true;
    this.media.play();
  }
}
```

music.ts (the component that calls the modal):

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Modal, NavController, Loading} from 'ionic-angular';
import {ModalsContentPage} from '../player/player';
import {AlbumPage} from '../album/album';
import {ConnectService} from '../../providers/connect-service/connect-service';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/music/music.html',
  providers: [ConnectService]
})
export class MusicPage {
  public releases: any;
  private loading;

  constructor(private navController: NavController, private connectService: ConnectService) {
    this.loading = Loading.create();
    this.loadReleases();
  }

  openModal(release) {
    let modal = Modal.create(ModalsContentPage, release);
    this.navController.present(modal);
  }

  goToOtherPage() {
    //push another page onto the history stack
    //causing the nav controller to animate the new page in
    this.navController.push(AlbumPage);
  }

  loadReleases() {
    this.navController.present(this.loading);
    this.connectService.loadReleases()
      .then(data => {
        this.releases = data;
        this.loading.dismiss();
      });
  }
}
```

Apologies if things are a bit spaghettified, I've been commenting stuff out trying to get different techniques to work.

Comment: Post more code, your component.

Comment: @dfsq Added all my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the issue you're having, but you can specify what to do when the `modal` is dismissed, like this:

```
openModal(release) {
  let modal = Modal.create(ModalsContentPage, release);

  // New code
  modal.onDismiss(data => {
      this.playerService.setRelease(data);
  });

  this.navController.present(modal);
}
```

That way, when the `modal` is dismissed, you will still be able to save the data using your service. You can find more information about the `Modal API` [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/modal/Modal/).

======================================

**EDIT:**

Just like I mentioned in the comment, try this:

Instead of registering the `service` as a `provider` in the `Component`:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './build/pages/player/player.html',
  providers: [PlayerService, ...]
})
```

Register it in the `ionicBootstrap` from your `app.ts` file like this:

```
ionicBootstrap(myApp, [PlayerService], {});
```

That way we can be sure that **the same instance** of the service will be used in the entire app (so, it will be a `singleton`).

Comment: This still is not working. I can confirm it will save within my music.ts when the modal dismisses, but when I call it when I open my modal up again it is still 'undefined'. I'm trying to keep data in my service because the modal is created and destroyed frequently.

Comment: We can try the following.. I suspect that the issue is because a new instance of the service is being created each time the component is loaded. Why don't you add the `PlayerService` in the `bootstrap` of the app, instead of doing that in the `component`? That way the service will be a **singleton** and the same instance will be use in the entire application.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.playerService.setRelease(this params get ( 'release')..); 
console.log(this playerService getStoredRelease ()..);         // This works just after it is stored.
```

**My Service:**

```
setRelease (release) {this. release = release; GetStoredRelease} () {return this. free; }
```

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. When was `GetStoredRelease` defined and why are there spaces everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

```
  providers: [PlayerService, ConnectService]
```

That line creates a new instance of the service, which would have your variables uninitialized.

Instantiate the service either in your bootstrap, or MusicPage providers line. Then load the service as you do in your constructor to access the instantiated service.